# Sending data to HDFS file system depending on the group

Tags: hive

I have a big data set in cassandra where I used hive to analyze and send data to hdfs file system. I am wondering is it possible to group by the appName and depending on the appName I send my data to differant hdfs file systems (Please note app names are not predefined)

appName  Data

a1       abc

a1       pqr

a1       qwe

a2   my

a2       data

a2       abc

a2       bnm

a3       ewr

a3       asf

a4       abc123

a1 dataset ->/apps/a1
a2 dataset ->/apps/a2
ect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamic partitions: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-DynamicpartitionInsert might suit you.
you wont be able to choose the path in HDFS but different apps will go to different folders.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the reply however, my problem is my appnames are not predefined so in your example INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE page_view PARTITION(dt='2008-06-08', country='US')
       SELECT pvs.viewTime, pvs.userid, pvs.page_url, pvs.referrer_url, null, null, pvs.ip WHERE pvs.country = 'US' I do not no the value of 'US' before hand will that be possible can it be parameterized?